# How can I pass an unquoted string with spaces as a quoted argument?

Tags: bash, quoting

Better explained with an example.  I am writing a simple wrapper (a function in my .bashrc) around the mail command.

Here is my current function which doesn't work correctly:

```
function email_me() { echo "$@" | mail -s "\"$@\"" myaddress@email.com; }
```

Here is my desired usage - this would send an email with both the subject and body set to `testing 1 2 3`.  Note I specifically do not want to have to put quotes in manually.

```
~$ email_me testing 1 2 3
```

Thus I want the string replacement to occur like this:

```
echo "testing 1 2 3" | mail -s "testing 1 2 3" myaddress@email.com
```

However no matter what I try, it's as though the -s argument doesn't have quotes around it, and email an email with the subject `"testing`is sent to the following recipients: 1, 2, 3, and myaddress@email.com

How can I make the -s argument consider "testing 1 2 3" to be a single string?

Comment: A little bit about why your `"\"$@\""` approach doesn't work: `$@`, when in double quotes, expands to `"$1" "$2"`... with split words, and `\"` is a literal quote, so what you end up with is `"\"$1"` as the first word, `"$2"` as the second word, ... `"$N\""` as the last word. Read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html for details of expansion.

Comment: Yes, just trying to make it super trivial to send myself a one-line email from the command line.  And thanks for the echo suggestion; that works perfectly!

Comment: @4ae1e1 Feel free to add the echo version as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Replace `$@` with `$*` and your function should work as expected. No need to for the escaped quotes `\"`

Comment: The comment above is right (assuming the first char of `IFS` is a space). I was temporarily confused.

Comment: Try this `function email_me() { echo "$@" | mail -s "$*" myaddress@email.com; }`

Comment: Unless you know your email message will never contain anything the shell will try to expand before passing it to your function, you are far better off simply resigning yourself to typing the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using

```
function email_me() { printf %s\\n "$*" | mail -s "$*" myaddress@email.com; }
```

- `"$*"` is indeed the special variable containing all arguments together in one string
- using `printf` instead of `echo` saves you from suprises with `-n` `-e` and whatever else your implementation of `echo` supports.

Still, there will be situations where you'll have to quote the arguments to `email_me` to avoid globbing and preserve whitespace:

```
email_me 2 * 2 = 4
[sends you all file names in current directory]
email_me a   b
[sends "a b" with only one space]
```